# Browser/OS support fonts

Tags: css, fonts

Where can I find a list of browser safe fonts? I mean fonts I can use in my webpages which will be displayed correctly in different browsers and versions both with Windows and Mac.

UPDATE:

Yes, I know how to search with Google. I just thought someone at this forum could give me a link to a matrix with font/browser/browserversion/os support of fonts. Like http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html for CSS support.

I found something that comes close to what I meant:
http://www.upsdell.com/BrowserNews/res_fonts.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are cross-browser, cross platfom web safe fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130790/what-are-cross-browser-cross-platfom-web-safe-fonts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are such lists:

- http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html

These is just one good link from a quick google search for "safe web font".

You can learn quite a lot from the wikipedia entry for [Web Typography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web-safe_fonts).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the exact answer you were searching, but you can use more fonts than the web-safe ones with services like Cufón:

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a closer look

Answer (score 0):

A quick search revealed the following list:
http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Google is your friend, too:
http://www.google.com/search?q=web+safe+fonts

Comment: Yes, I know. But there's a lot of crappy info on the net. I was hoping to get a advice from the experts @ SO ;-)

Comment: an alternative approach might be the usage of @font-face, the fontsquirrel will tell you more how to use this: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 0):

Go for most common fonts between all domains. I would suggest Verdana, it is probably one of the widely used font, which is supported by almost all OS.

Or go from one of the following list

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Bookman Old Style', serif;
font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;
font-family: Courier, monospace;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
font-family: Garamond, serif;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
font-family: 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif;
font-family: 'MS Serif', 'New York', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif;
font-family: Symbol, sans-serif;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-family: Webdings, sans-serif;
font-family: Wingdings, 'Zapf Dingbats', sans-serif;
```

Comment: I just extracted the list from @matt_asbury's answer :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Serve WOFF 2.0  variant to browsers that support it.
Serve WOFF      variant to the majority of browsers.
Serve TTF       variant to old Android (below 4.4) browsers.
Serve EOT       variant to old IE (below IE9) browsers.
```