# Is there a modern list of web-safe fonts?

Tags: html, css

If they are on an ancient browser let them burn.

Comment: Aren't web-safe fonts the ones installed in all OS? Did you mean render-safe?

Comment: it appears as though the initial abusive and negative comments from the moderators were removed. -- also my comments were removed.

Comment: I would vote to re-open this question.  It is an incredibly important issue for web-designers, and it is not an easy find on Google.  In addition, this is not a tool or library, and while it may end up being an offsite resource, it is no more a request for an offsite resource than most other requests I find on this site.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130790/what-are-cross-browser-cross-platfom-web-safe-fonts

Answer (score 4):

Just use what you want and gradually fall back to platform defaults and finally generic defaults:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
```

If the user's browser doesn't support external fonts, they will have to put up with the browser-chosen default fonts. Those should always be present.

Answer (score 2):

...not really.

There are *very* old web-safe fonts.

Now, there are web-safe font-stacks.
Different operating systems and different programs (like Photoshop/InDesign/et cetera) have their own sets of fonts.

So learn to pick similar/appropriate font-stacks, so that Windows 7/8, MacOS X.[whatever] and updated Linux users can have a similar experience, and then have fallback fonts for people on older systems.

Answer (score 0):

web-safe fonts have always been a lie with most sites proposing web-safe fonts ignoring anything but current windows and osx (hint: there are lots of other web clients, from android to linux passing through chromebooks…), inventing data about others, or ignoring unicode coverage (so their web-safe fonts only work for English text, sometimes not even including the euro symbol which is quite common nowadays).

The only actual web-safe fonts are the standard aliases such as monospace defined in the css specs.